# Why don’t consonants have a definite pitch?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, consonants

Is it because consonants are too fast or too slow that we perceive them as indefinite pitches?

Comment: Try saying a consonant like t or p without a vowel sound. It's impossible. A consonant on its own does not have pitch. A person has to say something for pitch.  Also, pitch is not something that is identified with that kind of thing, it's at the level of utterances. https://www.learngrammar.net/a/what-is-pitch-explained-with-examples Speed and pitch are not necessarily related. You can have high pitch to your voice and speak slowly.

Comment: It's absolutely not impossible to say a consonant without a vowel sound, especially but not exclusively continuants..

Answer (score 3):

Well, some of them do. When you're humming, you're producing a `[m]` sound at a particular pitch. In general, any consonants that involve the vocal cords vibrating will have a pitch.

Some of them don't, though, because pitch is a property of a *periodic* sound. It measures how quickly a certain pattern repeats. If there's no repeating pattern, the pitch is undefined.

It's the same reason many percussion instruments don't have a definite pitch. When you make a `[s]` sound, for example, you're producing a lot of aperiodic noise without repeating patterns in it.